# rendering a reflection on a texture

Tags: graphics, reflection-rendering

I want to render reflection on a planar surface but the reflecting surface has a texture mapped onto it.Would the normal technique of using stencil buffer and then blending in the reflected image with the reflecting surface in this case?
If not then could some one suggest me how to render reflection on a surface that has a texture mapped onto it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should work as long as you use the proper blending technique.

Comment: well thanks..I have done it successfully..was missing a line in the actual code,due to which I was stuck

Comment: @nodddy: You may want to answer your own question in that case and put the problem code in (with the solution, so people can compare) so that later on if someone runs into the same problem, and stumbles across this question, they can find the answer quickly

Comment: @Samaursa why would he do that if it's closed as "too localized"? :(

Comment: @ashes999: It wasn't when I commented :P